# I have two concerns on the highlighted part of this text

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I have a miniature Australian shepherd who is my world and my baby, her name is Whiskee. Most of the time when I am at home we are outside running around or going for walks. I love to workout and stay in shape. I am currently going back to school to obtain my second bachelors in Nurse in hopes for one day to become a Nurse Practitioner. I am a very strong independent woman who also needs to her alone time. **I admire love and cherish every moment of my life with the special people in it** . I will do anything for my family for family is a very important aspect in my life. I am looking for someone who is down to have fun, watch football together, and is just wanting to take things slow.

When she says " ...I admire love and cherish every moment of my life eith the special people in it" ,

1. Do "admire" & "love" refer to the affection of speaker towards other or affection of other towards the speaker?
2. Who the word "people" refers to? family and relatives or a group of friends?

Comment: This sounds like a profile on a dating site. If proper English is a concern to you, you might consider some of the half-dozen or so other errors in grammar, usage, and punctuation in the passage cited.  If you just care if she sounds like a nice person, don't quibble about whom she cherishes now—what matters is whether she can make room to include **you** as one of her "special people"!  And simply by listing on a dating site, she is strongly suggesting that she wants to add a man to that "special" list.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very badly written sentence, so don't worry about not understanding it first time.

"admire" and "love" come right after the word "I", so it's the speaker who admires and loves.  Who or what she admires and loves is not clear.

The 'special people' could be anyone she thinks of as special, but most likely refers to her family and close friends.

I think what she means to say is:

"I admire and love the special people in my life, and cherish every moment I spend with them."

Comment: It could also mean "I admire and cherish the special people in my life, and love every moment I spend with them." As you say, it's a badly-written sentence.